# X(t) follows a Brownian Motion. What is P(X(T) and X(2T) >0)?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $X(t)$ follows a Brownian Motion. 
What is $P(X(T)>0 \cap X(2T)>0)$?

Running MC simulations I found out $\frac{3}{8}$ but I cannot prove it mathematically.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{P}[X(T)>0 \text{ and } X(2T) > 0]$?

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Let's denote the event
$$
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \left\{ x-h < X(T) < x+h \right\} = A_x.
$$
This is intuitively just the continuous analog of the discrete event $\{X(T) = x\}$.

Also denote the pdf and cdf of $X(T)$ as $f_T$ and $F_T$, respectively.

Note that
$$
\begin{split}
p &= \mathbb{P}[X(T)>0 \text{ and } X(2T)>0] \\
  &= \int_0^{\infty}
       \mathbb{P}\left[X(T)>0 \text{ and } X(2T)>0 \left| A_x \right.\right]
       \mathbb{P}[A_x] dx \\
  &= \int_0^{\infty}
       \mathbb{P}\left[X(2T)>0 \left| A_x \right.\right]
       f_T(x) dx\\
  &= \int_0^{\infty}
       \mathbb{P}\left[X(T+T) - X(T) > -x \left| A_x \right.\right]
       f_T(x) dx \quad \text{independent increments implies}\\ 
  &= \int_0^{\infty}
       \mathbb{P}\left[X(T) > -x \right]
       f_T(x) dx\\
  &= \int_0^{\infty}
       (1-F_T(-x))
       f_T(x) dx\\
\end{split}
$$
Can you take it from here?

**UPDATE**

As you correctly noticed, using $F_T(-x) = 1-F_T(x)$, you get
$$
p = \int_0^\infty F_T(x) f_T(x) dx
$$
and the integral can be substituted using $u = F_T(x)$. What do you get?

Comment: Then it's $\int_{0}^{\infty} (f_{T}(x)-f_T(x)F_T(x))dx$?

Comment: @Arthurim corrected mistake in last line of the answer and updated for your comment. Please see the update